# Functional component not logging current state but does with class component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I created a functional component Room and within that component, I have a function showCurrentState() that logs the current state. I have a regular class WebSocketInstance that I pass showCurrentState() to.

The issue is that when I add data to my state messages and I call checkState() which calls WebSocketInstance.activateCallback() which calls showCurrentState(), I expect my updated data to show up but for some reason, the empty array is logged.

The reason for using a separate class is that my WebSocketInstance needs to connect to Django channels in my backend. I'm sure that's not the issue since when I convert my functional component to a class component the updated state is logged correctly. I'm assuming there's something wrong with my functional component but I don't know what.

My functional component

```
const Room = (props) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  let params = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // I pass my function
    WebSocketInstance.addCallbacks(showCurrentState)
  }, [params.roomName])

  const showCurrentState = () => {
    // When this function is called from activateCallback() messages is still empty
    // regardless if messages has data
    console.log(messages)
  }
  const displayNewMessages = (msg) => {
    setMessages([...messages, {isAuthor: true, username: "lezlus", message: msg}]);
  }
  const checkState = () => {
    WebSocketInstance.activateCallback();
  }
}
```

My WebSocketInstance

```
class WebSocketInstance {
  callbacks = {};

  constructor() {
    this.socketRef = null;
  }

  addCallbacks(newMessageCallback) {
    this.callbacks["newMessage"] = newMessageCallback;  
  }

  activateCallback() {
    this.callbacks["newMessage"]();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution. I'm guessing since I added the callback when the component is first loaded it only holds the original state which is an empty array. I added the callback outside of the useEffect(). This still works when I switch to a different Room route.

```
const Room = (props) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  let params = useParams();
  WebSocketInstance.addCallbacks(() => {
    console.log(messages)
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component mounted on route change")
    console.log(params.roomName);
    setMessages([]);
  }, [params.roomName])
}
```

This is another solution I found. I use useEffect() to track changes in the messages and I reassign the callback.

```
const Room = (props) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  let params = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component mounted first time")
    console.log(params.roomName);
    setMessages([]);
    WebSocketInstance.addCallbacks(showCurrentState)
  }, [params.roomName])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("messages changed")
    WebSocketInstance.addCallbacks(showCurrentState)
  }, [messages])
}
```